# how can extract single character before the number in a string

Tags: sed, grep, string

I have a list that contains the names of hosts available in our company.

For example :

- gswast03
- gkjbossp1
- frdwop04

The last characters `t`, `p`, `q` before the number represent the environment of the host. All strings end with a number.

- `t` for test
- `p` for prod
- `q` for qas

I need a reqular expression to obtain the character that is leading to number at the and of the host name (I need a solution for a single string not all list in a file)

For example :

```
gswast03
```

In this string, I just want to extract `t` character.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is that list input line `frdwop04` supposed to be `frdwoq04` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've tagged the question with `grep` and `sed`, I assume that list of string is expressed as one item per line of some text input.

Then:

```
sed -n 's/^.*\([^[:digit:]]\)[[:digit:]]\{1,\}$/\1/p' < that-input
```

or (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible built with perl-like regexp support):

```
grep -Po '\D(?=\d+$)' < that-input
```

would output the non-digit character that precede trailing digits in lines that end in a non-digit followed by 1 or more digit.

Both use regexps to do the matching but `sed` uses basic regular expressions while `grep -P` uses perl-like regular expressions.

Some `sed` implementations support `-P` as well, but not the most common ones. Several support `-E` for extended regular expressions which is yet another dialect of regular expressions. With those:

```
sed -E -n 's/^.*([^[:digit:]])[[:digit:]]+$/\1/p' < that-input
```

Or you could just use `perl` itself:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /(\D)\d+$/' < that-input
```

(beware `perl` works at byte-level by default instead of character level, see the `-C` option to tell it to interpret the input as UTF-8 characters, or `-Mopen=locale` to decode/encode input/output as per the locale's encoding like `grep`/`sed` typically do).

or `pcregrep`, the sample `grep` implementation that comes with libpcre (the library used by GNU `grep -P`):

```
pcregrep -o1 '(\D)\d+$' < that-input
```

Answer (score 2):

With plain bash

```bsh
shopt -s extglob
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  tmp=${host%%+([[:digit:]])}   # strip the trailing digits
  echo "$host => ${tmp: -1}"    # extract the last character
done
```

```
gswast03 => t
gkjbossp1 => p
frdwop04 => p
```

Or with regex matching:

```bsh
for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  if [[ $host =~ ([^[:digit:]])[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
    echo "$host => ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`.*([pqt])\d+$`

Matches any characters, followed by a p, q or t and one or more digits. The match group is the single letter you're interested in.

Comment: No need for the leading `.*` since the RE is bound to `$`

Comment: Technically, indeed, but it helps convey the intention if you're new to regexes.

Comment: That regexp wouldn't work in any standard UNIX tool so you should say which tool(s) you have in mind to run it in, what options it'd need, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will work using any sed in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ sed 's/.*\([^0-9]\).*/\1/' file
t
p
q
```

The above was run against this input file:

```
$ cat file
gswast03
gkjbossp1
frdwoq04
```